# Windows Azure - need to stop a WorkerRole from within

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I previousely worked on some Windows Services that can stop automatically when encountering critical errors.

Migrating those to Windows Azure, in WorkerRole, I'd like to do the same : being able **to stop the WorkerRole** execution from within.

I just encounter a little problem...

When the ***Run*** method ends,
the WorkerRole ***OnStop*** method is triggered,
then it's restarted...
From what I've read, it's a normal behavior for a WorkerRole.

Then my question is : how to tell it '*job complete, do not restart please*'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure this is actually possible. 
You could use

```
Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
```

But since the worker role is deployed onto the cloud you will still have to pay I think The only way to actually stop stop this is by suspending the whole role from the Azure Platform.

Comment: Doing something like this will still incur cost: the cost is based on instances that are deployed, not on the actual number of CPU cycles or similar.

Comment: Cost is not my problem here. Criticals errors and restart are the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can't stop a specific role instance. You can scale down from, say, 3 instances to 1, but you can't choose which ones to terminate.

If you're talking about a single-instance worker role that needs to start up, process something, then shut down (say, once a day), consider moving this role into its own deploymnt. Then, using the management API, deploy it, let it run for an hour (or however long you need it), and then suspend+delete it.

Comment: Like I said "when encountering a critical error" and "from within". I want my WorkerRole to be smart, not to have an operator to perform checks all the time.

Comment: If you have a queue-based processing pipeline, you can encapsulate all queue processing and, if an exception is thrown, treat the queued command as a poison message, remove it from the queue, store it in a table or elsewhere, and send yourself a message to further investigate.

You can also programmatically take your instance out of the load balancer, then send yourself a note. At this point, you can RDP to the instance to diagnose what the issue is.

Comment: Interesting way of working, thanks for sharing. In the facts it's not a pipeline it's a scheduler based on different tasks executed periodically. The "critical errors" can happen if the database stop working at the moment a task is marked as complete. This can happen in very rares cases, and can really be a problem. So it's an "extreme" cases that needs to be adressed. Stopping the scheduler for further investingation is what we currently do with the bots working as Windows Service. Could you tell me how you can "programmatically take your instance out of the load balancer" ?

Comment: Each Windows Azure role has PowerShell pre-installed, and there are a set of Windows Azure PowerShell cmdlets pre-installed as well. Simply call Set-RoleInstanceStatus -Busy. See this blog post by Mike Wood (Windows Azure MVP) for more info on the built-in cmdlets: http://mvwood.com/blog/new-powershell-cmdlets-on-azure/

Answer (score 0):

If your particular role uses only a single instance, you can lower the instance count for that role to 0 through the management API. Switching of a particular role is not a supported feature, but you can get it to work by building a kill switch service that you can call on a particular instance and simultaneously lower the number of instances. This requires a bit of plumbing code, but is doable.

Comment: You can't set instance count to 0. You can only suspend, and then delete, your deployment. For tasks requiring a role to run only for a short period of time (say, once every 24 hours), consider putting it in a separate deployment.

Comment: Good point! You should have made your comment an answer, that way I could upvote it :-) Suspend and delete can be done through management API as well, luckily. An alternative could be to run an extra-small instance to keep cost down.

Comment: Cost is not the problem here, and i don't want the task to run a given amount of time. I just want to avoid execution of a task that thrown a critical error. I'll search into the API if it can be executed from within a worker role and if it can suspend itself ^^

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your question correctly.... The worker role process is stopped but then gets started again?

I have run into issues where, if the worker role runs for a long time it essentially starts again. What happens is that Azure assumes that after a long time (generally 30 seconds) it assumes the role has hung and will write the Message back to the worker queue to ensure the process is completed.

I am taking a stab here, but is it possible in your scenario that the stopping of the worker role does not result in the message being deleted from the Worker Role message queue? If so, you may want to see if there is way to explicitly delete the message you are processing before you terminate the process.

More info here

http://guerillaprogrammer.com/jakew/post/2010/03/23/Expiring-Azure-Queue-Message.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Thread.Suspend() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.suspend.aspx and if you want to resume it again use Thread.Resume()

Answer (score 0):

recently I come across the same problem.
My problem is fixed by commenting worker role part from ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg,ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg and ServiceDefinition.csdef file and Packaging the project.